# How to fix mismatch reference in the manifest and the identity of the downloaded assembly LINQPad.exe

Tags: c#, .net, linqpad

I just finished my c# application in visual studio. I have encountered an issue when I publish the application and try to install it in my machine as well as others. Before the installation completes I get this error:

Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.

- Activation of C:\Users\JAP\Desktop\Ver\Diagnostics.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:

  - Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly LINQPad.exe.

  Same error on three machines (all running windows 10 64 bit)

  The following code is where I use the LINQPad library
  (Have many cases)
  The way I added the LINQPad is by Adding a reference to the .exe , located in (C:\Program Files (x86)\LINQPad5).

Note that in the csproj it shows like this:

```
<Reference Include="LINQPad, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21353812cd2a2db5, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
<SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
<HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\LINQPad5\LINQPad.exe</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I call the reference by

```
using LINQPad;
```

The things that I have tried and none of them worked are:

1) Enable ClickOnce security settings and full trust application checked

2) Create app without a manifest and with manifests.

3) Unchecked prefer 32-bit

4) Optimize code is enabled and DEBUG / TRACE constant

5) Removing from csproj the reference

6) Clean, build , rebuild

But nothing seems to work

```
private void gpuinfos(List<string> dataElements)
        {

ManagementObjectSearcher mosgpu = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", $"SELECT {String.Join(",", dataElements)} FROM Win32_VideoController");

foreach (ManagementObject gpuInfo in mosgpu.Get())
            {
                foreach (var anElementName in dataElements)
                {

  string valuegpu Convert.ToString(gpuInfo[anElementName]);

 valuegpu.Dump(anElementName);

switch (anElementName)
                    {
                        case "Name":
                            NameGPU.Text = valuegpu;
                            break;
...
                    }
                 }
              }
           }

More Error Details:

    Following errors were detected during this operation.
        * [6/26/2019 12:26:46 AM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (RefDefValidation)
            - Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly LINQPad.exe.
            - Source: System.Deployment
            - Stack trace:
                at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
                at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.DownloadModifiedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
                at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.OnModified()
                at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
                at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
                at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
                at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
                at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
                at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
                at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
                at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
                at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to reference a 32-bit assembly from a 64-bit app. You will need to either reference the AnyCPU version of LINQPad, or the LINQPad NuGet package.

Comment: Hello sir , just tried both of those , sadly the error remains. maybe it will help you if I send you all my project options.: Manifest: 1) Create app without a manifest                            2) Net Framework 4.7.2 , 3) Optimize code + debug and trace are defined (checked)   4) Enable ClickOnce security settings (checked) and fully trust application                  If any information can be helpfull, please let me know . Thank you in advance